# Replace Route action function with a controller

Tags: php, laravel

How could I add this function:

```php
function(){
  return "Message sent";
}
```

To this part of code:

```php
Route::get('/send-testenrollment', [TestsEnrollmentController::class, 'sendTestNotification']);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#available-router-methods) of the `get` method is:

```php
Route::get($uri, $callback);
```

[callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) can be an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), the name of a function or the name of an **object's method**

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

**More accurately**. The definition of the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get` method is:

```php
public static function get(string $uri, array|string|callable|null $action = null): \Illuminate\Routing\Route
```

---

You are trying to switch from using [basic routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#basic-routing):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/send-testenrollment', function () {
    return "Message sent";
});
```

To using [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#basic-controllers):

```
php artisan make:controller TestsEnrollmentController
```

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\TestsEnrollmentController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
Route::get('/send-testenrollment', [TestsEnrollmentController::class, 'sendTestNotification']);
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestsEnrollmentController extends Controller
{
    public function sendTestNotification()
    {
        return "Message sent";
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead of using a basic route I should implement controllers like this:?                    
 use App\Http\Controllers\TestsEnrollmentController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
Route::get('/send-testenrollment', [TestsEnrollmentController::class, 'sendTestNotification']);
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestsEnrollmentController extends Controller
{
    public function sendTestNotification()
    {
        return "Message sent";
    }
}

Comment: @karymelopez Yes, controllers help you organise your project. Do you have more questions